# Removing lines spaces in a ggplot2 label within a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

Does anyone know how to remove the space between the lines of a label in the geom_text label function in ggplot? Below is the code I have but introduces a huge gap among the lines, see in the image.[image: linear regression output with p and R² with a big space]
`

```
s + geom_text(aes(x=45, y=0.8, size=19,
                  label= "R²= 0.1\np = 0.17"))
```

`

I do not know what I could do. Have already searched online and the only resources are related to axis labels

Comment: What is `s` here? I'm guessing it is a previous plot or object. It is also helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Thank you Shawn, will do it next time. S is a plot in which I wanted to insert the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `lineheight` aesthetic is 1.2. Set it to a smaller value to decrease the spacing between lines of text.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = 45, y = 0.8, size = 19, label = "R²= 0.1\np = 0.17"),
            lineheight = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

(Additionally, you might want to set the font size outside the `aes()` function if you only have a single font size)

Comment: I don't know what happened to my previous reply, but it seems that it didn't go through. Thank you @teunbrand ! It worked perfectly.